# Repeating alarms between two dates

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

I've searched for examples of how to implement such a problem but couldn't find anything that could solve my problem so I'm asking you for an advice how to solve it.

I have to implement an alarm that fires every day at a specific time during the period between two specified dates.

Up to now I have a repeating alarm firing every day at a specific time but not specified until when to repeat...

Any advice and ideas will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you ask a question, it is polite to comment/decline/accept on any answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to set an `repeating` `Alarm` from `Date1` to `Date2`.
For `Date1`, there is no problem for you since it is working.
Set an `alarm` for `Date2` and when that alarm is fired cancel `Date1` repeating alarm.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

Lets say you wanted to set a repeating alarm, that first triggered at a 'random' time between two hours (e.g. 0100 - 0500) in the day, and then always triggered at that same time of day again every 24 hours.

```
private long getTimeOfNextWidgetAutoUpdateInMilliseconds(Calendar now, int startHour, int endHour){
    // calc the time diff in milliseconds from now until a 'random' time between startHour and endHour
    // ensure to +1 day if the time has already passed
}

private void createAutoRefreshAlarm(Context context, long initialTriggerTimeInMillis,
            long intervalInMillis) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = getAlarmManager(context);
        PendingIntent widgetRefreshPi = getWidgetRefreshAlarmPendingIntent(context);
        setRepeatingAlarm(initialTriggerTimeInMillis, intervalInMillis, widgetRefreshPi,
                alarmManager);

        ApplicationData.setAppDataBoolean(WIDGET_REFRESH_ALARM_SERVICE_INITITATED, true);
    }

    private static void setRepeatingAlarm(long initialTriggerTimeInMillis, long intervalInMillis,
            PendingIntent widgetRefreshPi, AlarmManager alarmManager) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                initialTriggerTimeInMillis,
                intervalInMillis,
                widgetRefreshPi);
    }

private PendingIntent getWidgetRefreshAlarmPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
    }

 private static AlarmManager getAlarmManager(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        return alarmManager;
    }
```

I would then have the following in the WidgetProvider class:

```
@Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);

        int startHour = 1;
        int endHour = 5;
        long initialTriggerTimeInMillis = getTimeOfNextWidgetAutoUpdateInMilliseconds(
                Calendar.getInstance(),
                startHour,
                endHour);

        long intervalInMillis = 86400000; // 24 hours
        createAutoRefreshAlarm(context, initialTriggerTimeInMillis, intervalInMillis);
    }
```

This should get you going, I've cut+pasted from my own project, so there may be a few errors.

Also, remember to cancel your alram in the `onDisabled()` method of your `WidgetProvider.

There are other scenarios that delete the alarm that you should consider, e.g. ON BOOT